# Unable to install R package Cairo

Tags: r, redhat, cairo

I am trying to install the package Cairo on RedHat running R version 3.2.3. So far I have tried:

```
install.packages("Cairo") 
R CMD INSTALL Cairo_1.5-9.tar.gz
```

Both the approaches giving me the same error below.

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Cairo', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so':
libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

I have tried the same logging in as root. Only the path for the shared library was different, error remained the same.

I have also tried installing packages mentioned below using

```
yum install cairo cairo-devel cairomm-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel pango pango-devel pangomm pangomm-devel
```

Also, I have X11 libraries installed.

Comment: Please read the error message: `libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file` Install png headers. Something like `sudo yum install libpng-devel`.

Comment: Just did a "sudo yum install libpng", succesful. Tried " R CMD INSTALL Cairo_1.5-9.tar.gz" Exact same error as before.

Comment: It is **not** what I suggested.

Comment: Sorry, even that got iinstalled by doing "sudo yum install libpng".

Comment: **I SAID `sudo yum install libpng-devel`!!!**

Comment: libpng-devel-1.2.49-2.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: You need version **1.5**.

Comment: Ok. Let me try installing. Will get back.